# double[] cannot be converted to double

Tags: java

I have a problem on Codewars. When I run this code on IDEA IntelliJ it's work, when run on Codewars error double[] canno't be converted to double. I return double, not double[], what problem with Codewars or my code?

```
import java.util.*;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;
 public class Kata {
    public static double findUniq(double arr[]) {
      return Arrays.asList(arr).stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(e -> e)).entrySet().stream().min((e1,e2) -> e1.getValue().size()-e2.getValue().size()).get().getValue().get(0);
    }
}
```

On IDEA IntelleJ

```
import java.util.*;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

public class CodeWars {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Double[] doubles = new Double[]{ 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 2.0, 1.0, 1.0 };
        Double db = Arrays.stream(doubles).collect(Collectors.groupingBy(e -> e)).entrySet().stream().min((e1, e2) -> e1.getValue().size()-e2.getValue().size()).get().getValue().get(0);
        System.out.println(db);

    }
}
```

Comment: `Arrays.asList(arr)` is returning a `List<double[]>`, not a `List<Double>`. Just use `Arrays.stream(arr)`, which will return a `DoubleStream` (and if you need a `Stream<Double>` just call `boxed()` on the `DoubleStream`).

Comment: Hey, thank you for your reply. I want to get double and don't really understand how to do that

Answer (score 0):

I've had the same problem and adding this import into CodeWars terminal helped:

import java.util.stream.DoubleStream;

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).